# Pytorch's .backward() stops python with no error

Tags: python, pytorch

When doing .backwards() in the code attached python simply just stops without printing any error trace in the cli, what could be going wrong here?

```
output = F.softmax(output, dim=1)
argmax_values = output.max(dim=-1, keepdim=True)[1]
model.zero_grad(set_to_none=True)
print(output, argmax_values)
torch.gather(output, -1, argmax_values).backward(gradient=torch.ones_like(argmax_values)) #Python stops here
```

Torch version : '1.9.0+cu111'

I tried saving the output of torch.gather in its own variable and then do .backward() after to make sure that is failing on .backward() and it is.

Comment: It's hard to say without more context, but one potential issue might be that you're not operating on tensors that have `requires_grad=True`. In PyTorch, only tensors with requires_grad=True can have their gradients computed, which is required for the .backward() operation.

Comment: could you add a [minimal and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example?

Comment: @ndrwnaguib Its a bit hard without including the pretrained model that I'm running this on. I did try to run 

model = nn.Linear(10, 3)
input = torch.randn(2, 10, requires_grad=True)
images = input.detach().clone()
output = model(input)
targets = torch.tensor([0, 2])

and use them as the inputs, but it did not reproduce it :(.

Comment: @eshirvana the tensor created by torch.gather has grad_fn=<GatherBackward>, should this meet the requirement?

I would think that doing .backward() on a tensor without gradients enabled would throw an error.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Updating to torch version 0.11.0+cu113 solved this issue for me. I'm still left without an explanation to why it did not work on 1.9.0+cu111, regardless I guess I would consider this case closed for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to torch version 1.11.0+cu113 solved this issue for me. I'm still left without an explanation to why it did not work on 1.9.0+cu111, regardless I guess I would consider this case closed for me.

Comment: do you mean `1.11.0+cu113`?

Comment: Sorry about that @ndrwnaguib, you're correct, its 1.11.0+cu113. I updated my post :).